# window.close current window when another window.open is requested

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open, window.closed

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

I have two different window.open requests depending on if a user clicks on either a mobile button or a webcam button.

- a **mobcamWindow** will open with a certain (small) size when the mobile button is clicked
- a **webcamWindow** will open with a different (large) size when the webcam button is clicked

These windows will open fine and in the correct size, however if the webcam button is clicked while the (smaller) **mobcamWindow** is open, I want the current **mobcamWindow** to close and the new (larger) **webcamWindow** to open (in its correct size) and vice versa.

Currently, the window does not close, but the URL will change to the correct **mobcamWindow** & **webcamWindow** respectively, however the window will remain the same size.

I have tried to do window.resize which did not work, and window.close does not work either.

My code is as follows. (I have two functions to handle each **mobcamWindow** & **webcamWindow**, with an IF statement in each to check if **mobcamWindow** or **webcamWindow** is open, and to close it if it is.

```
var webcamWindow = null; // global variable
var mobcamWindow = null; // global variable

function openStreamPopupWebcam(elem) {

  if(webcamWindow == null || webcamWindow.closed)
  /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
     or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */

  { 

    if(mobcamWindow){
      mobcamWindow.close();
    }
    /*if mobile window is open, close mobile window*/

    webcamWindow = window.open(elem.href, "window", "width=470,height=320,resizable,status").focus();
    /* then create it. The new window will be created and
       will be brought on top of any other window. */

  }

}

function openStreamPopupMobile(elem) {

  if(mobcamWindow == null || mobcamWindow.closed)
  /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
     or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */

  { 

    if(webcamWindow){
      webcamWindow.close();
    }
    /*if mobile window is open, close mobile window*/

    mobcamWindow = window.open(elem.href, "window", "width=445,height=666,resizable,status").focus();
    /* then create it. The new window will be created and
       will be brought on top of any other window. */

  }

}
```

If you need any more information or are finding it hard to understand me please ask and I will try and explain as best I can.

Thank you.

Comment: Give different names for your windows, now both are named as `window`.

Comment: Now I feel like a fool. You are right, giving them separate names has solved the problem. I overlooked the "window" part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reinitialize the values to 'null' when those conditions are satisfied

```js
var webcamWindow = null; // global variable
var mobcamWindow = null; // global variable
function openStreamPopupWebcam(elem){
  if(webcamWindow == null || webcamWindow.closed){
    if(mobcamWindow){
      mobcamWindow.close();
      mobcamWindow = null;
    }
    webcamWindow = window.open(elem.href, "window", "width=470,height=320,resizable,status").focus();
  }
}
function openStreamPopupMobile(elem){
  if(mobcamWindow == null || mobcamWindow.closed){
    if(webcamWindow){
      webcamWindow.close();
      webcamWindow = null;
    }
    mobcamWindow = window.open(elem.href, "window", "width=445,height=666,resizable,status").focus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Teemu

> Give different names for your windows, now both are named as window. – Teemu

Thank you.

Also thank you Adarsh Mohan for pointing out that the values should be reinitialized to 'null' on close.